# Method to split addresses? Multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv, strsplit

**I need a method that will help me split addresses in my CSV file:**
I need to split full_address column into -> owner_street, owner_city:

1. 3661  SUNSWEPT DR  STUDIO CITY -> 3661  SUNSWEPT DR , STUDIO CITY
2. 0   PO BOX 78460  LOS ANGELES -> 0   PO BOX 78460 , LOS ANGELES
3. 68  E 89TH ST  LOS ANGELES -> 68  E 89TH ST, LOS ANGELES

But the problem is I don't have a delimiter that is consistently found in all addresses (because some are PO boxes).
I was thinking of first splitting normal street addresses by multiple delimiters:

```
import re
re.split('ST AVE PL LN DR',str)
```

Then splitting PO boxes where there is a number found: Something like this:

```
temp = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
res = temp.match(test_str).groups()
```

I would also like to keep the delimiter for both Normal Street Addresses as well as PO Boxes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At best you'd be making a guess which would then have to be verified against your input data anyway. The saying is GIGO: Garbage In, Garbage Out. The best place to apply effort here would be ensuring that future input is tidier, i.e. split into fields via CSV or other formats.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know, I received the data from the city... very messy. Initially the data came to me as: 16711 S Caress Ave Compton 90221. Very frustrating.

Comment: Mapping software like Google Maps uses a single line of input like this, but that's backed by a very mature parser/algorithm as well as a giant database. Maybe you could feed these addresses into the API of such software, allow it to process them for you, and then collect the tidied-up result?

Comment: There are databases of zip codes for use with Python. Perhaps use one of these to find the city name covered and then the split of the city from the rest is trivial.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks for the suggestions. @TigerhawkT3